# Azure CLI(Bash) remember/persistent variables

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azureportal

Is there a way to save/ make variables persistent even when CLI restarts/is closed?

Example: I open CLI on Azure and define a couple of variables, for instance:

```
MYRESOURCEGROUP=northeurope
```

if I echo this it will return northeurope

```
echo $MYRESOURCEGROUP
northeurope
```

When I restart CLI the variable is not remembered and I have to define it again.

It feels a bit strange to define all used variables each time I restart CLI. Any thoughts on this?

There are default variables but it seems to be prompt to error as I am switching between different resource groups.

Comment: Do you use Azure Cloud Shell in Bash?

Comment: Bash. An apology for not clearing this out in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that adding the following to your :`~/.bashrc`

```
# Avoid duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```